# How do I create a service on CentOS running as a different user than root?

Tags: centos, systemd, root, startup, services

I'm using CentOS 7.  I want to run a nodeJS script as a service but run the service as the "rails" user.  As root, I created the file /usr/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service, with the contents

```
[Unit]
Description=mydir nodejs server

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/rails/mydir/start.sh
ExecStop=/home/rails/mydir/stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What else do I need to do to get the service to run as the user I want?

Comment: It looks like a quick Google would produce some useful examples, including some right here on U&LSE.

Comment: Yeah but those are dealing with older versions of CentOS than what I listed in my question.  E.g. top Google result is https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=54865 but that deals with CenteOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the user and group under the `[Service]` heading:

```
User=rails
Group=rails
```

See [the credentials section of systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Credentials) for details.

Also, use `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` as the path for service files created by the system administrator instead of `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. See [Creating and Modifying systemd Unit Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files)